# Iterating through a binary sequence with some bits stuck to 1

Tags: algorithm, binary, iteration

Say I have a binary number `01100 = 12`, what's an efficient way to iterate starting with this number such that the bits already set to one remain set?

In this example the sequence would go

> 01100 = 12
>   01101 = 13
>   01110 = 14
>   01111 = 15
>   11100 = 28
>   11101 = 29
>   11110 = 30
>   11111 = 31

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: Not homework, just my brain getting stuck on my own projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the original value. Then every time you increment the dynamic value, or it with the original. In Java:

```
int orig = val;
while (true) {
    System.out.println(val);
    val = (val+1) | orig;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just increment and look at the binary, whenever a block of 1s gets cleared, it will  also increment the 0 past the end of that block.  So you can just count, and set the bits again on each iteration:

```
const unsigned n = 12;
unsigned i = n;

while (1) {
    // print i (or whatever)
    i = (i + 1) | n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int origin = 12;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((origin & i) != origin)
        continue;
    do_something(i);
}
```

Comment: Or, easier, `if ((origin & i) == origin) do_something(i);`, right?